# Can AWS Redshift Copy Command Ignore Extra Fields In Source File?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift

My original source file had 10 fields in it and these were copied into my redshift table using a COPY command and a column list containing the 10 table columns for mapping in the source file fields.

The source file has now had 4 extra fields added to the end so my copy command is now failing with the dreaded "Extra column(s) found" error.

I have scoured the aws copy docs and cannot find any switches or config to force these extra fields to be ignored - is my only option to fix it to add the 4 extra fields to the copy table and column list?

It seems strange that the copy command cannot tolerate what i would've thought is a non-breaking change.

Comment: What is the file format you are trying to load?  CSV or text I assume.  I suspect your best option is a COPY command with the number of columns that matches the text files.  Then INSERT the needed data into the target table.

Comment: it's a shapefile, but i think the copy behaviour is the same regardless of file type (not 100% sure on that tho!).

Comment: yes i have updated the column list to match the file, but my issue is that i want to avoid needing to make that change unless i do actually want those extra fields. in an api world, an interface can be modified with extra fields and the clients will continue working without change - i was hoping to have similar behaviour here as the file is externally sourced and we may not get advance notification of any changes within it. if the copy command could tolerate extra fields being ignored then we would have control over when or if to update our ingest copy

Comment: - without this capability, we have to expect issues in our copy process when we get an unexpected change in the source file and deal with the problem reactively, incurring downtime.

Comment: apologies for the split comment, i didn't know about the character limit :)

Comment: I've only done limited work with shape files so this comes from CSV/text file work but has a good chance of working in your case.  The FILLRECORD option will fill missing columns with NULLs - basically the opposite of what you want.  But you can add dummy columns to you ingest table DDL (... , dummy1, dummy2 etc) that cover the width of future expected data.  If the data is missing for these columns then they get NULL.

Comment: Good plan! I'm gonna raise it with our aws contact but for now this will do :)